# Pourquoi ne prononce-t-on pas la dernière lettre de bœuf ou os au pluriel ?

Tags: vocabulaire, prononciation

Au singulier, on prononce os « osse » et bœuf « beuffe ». Le *S* et le *F*, qui restent à l'écrit, ne sont pourtant pas prononcés et on dit « deux eaux » et « trois beus. »

Pourquoi ?

Comment: Et « œuf(s) » aussi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

D'après la [banque de dépannage linguistique de l'office québécois de la langue française](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3067) :

> En ancien français, on avait tendance à ne pas prononcer la consonne finale d’un mot lorsqu’elle était suivie du -s du pluriel. Ce phénomène serait à l’origine d’une hésitation, à partir du XVIe siècle, quant à la prononciation des mots bœuf, œuf et os, et ce, même au singulier, l’une ou l’autre des prononciations étant utilisées indifféremment. Ce n’est qu’au XIXe siècle que la distinction entre le singulier et le pluriel s’est fixée comme on la connaît aujourd'hui.

Comment: Cette hésitation qui est décrite ici est d'ailleurs la raison pour laquelle certaines personnes disent encore (dans les milieux ruraux): _un boeuf_ et le prononcent comme _un beu_.

Comment: Une incertitude règne encore aujourd’hui en certains endroits du Québec par rapport au mot *«ours»*. On entend ici et là que le pluriel se prononce sans le *S* final *(ce qui n’est plus la version officielle, mais ne change rien aux échanges que peuvent avoir les gens, et semble néanmoins être une [relique du passé](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/ours))*, et on l’entend même parfois au singulier, **un ourre**, ce qui serait sorti de la langue (européenne) il y a encore plus longtemps.